# Django - get values from a self-defined object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i am using Django to create an OneToOneField object for user with code below:

```
class ControlInformation(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    TURN_ON_OFF = (
        ('ON', 'On'),
        ('OFF', 'Off'),
    )

    AUTO_MANU = (
        ('ON', 'On'),
        ('OFF', 'Off'),
    )

    TEMP_DINNINGROOM = (
        ('HIGH', 'High'),
        ('MEDIUM', 'Medium'),
        ('LOW', 'Low'),
    )

    TEMP_LIVINGROOM = (
        ('HIGH', 'High'),
        ('MEDIUM', 'Medium'),
        ('LOW', 'Low'),
    )

    turn_on_off = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TURN_ON_OFF)
    auto_manu = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices=AUTO_MANU)
    temp_dinningroom = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TEMP_DINNINGROOM)
    temp_livingroom = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TEMP_LIVINGROOM)


#signal function: if a user is created, add control information to the user    
def create_control_information(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ControlInformation.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_control_information, sender=User)
```

Then, I created a form for this object with the code below:

```
class ControlInformationForm(forms.Form):

    TURN_ON_OFF = (
        ('ON', 'On'),
        ('OFF', 'Off'),
    )

    AUTO_MANU = (
        ('ON', 'On'),
        ('OFF', 'Off'),
    )

    TEMP_DINNINGROOM = (
        ('HIGH', 'High'),
        ('MEDIUM', 'Medium'),
        ('LOW', 'Low'),
    )

    TEMP_LIVINGROOM = (
        ('HIGH', 'High'),
        ('MEDIUM', 'Medium'),
        ('LOW', 'Low'),
    )

    on_off = forms.ChoiceField(label="on_off", choices=TURN_ON_OFF)
    auto_manu = forms.ChoiceField(label="auto_manu", choices=AUTO_MANU)
    temp_dinningroom = forms.ChoiceField(label="temp_dinningroom", choices=TEMP_DINNINGROOM)
    temp_livingroom = forms.ChoiceField(label="temp_livingroom", choices=TEMP_LIVINGROOM)
```

Finally, i used

```
ControlInformation = request.user.get_profile()
form=ControlInformationForm(request.POST)
```

in the views.py to get the value of ControlInformation object, but it dose not work ( Error: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'turn_on_off'). I think the problem happens because i used `request.user.get_profile()`. How can i modify this to get the value of ControlInformation object then modify and save() it?

Comment: You'll need to include more about views.py as the error is referring to a `UserProfile` object that isn't defined anywhere in your question.  Also, did you set `appname.ControlInformation` to `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` in settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ControlInformation = request.user.get_profile()` use:

```
instance = ControlInformation.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Some more tips:

- Use `ModelForm` to automagically create a form from your model.
- You can use a `BooleanField` instead of ON/OFF.

And you can use one lookup for two fields:

```
  TEMP = (
        ('HIGH', 'High'),
        ('MEDIUM', 'Medium'),
        ('LOW', 'Low'),
  )
```

Enjoy Django!